# The locally saved data is deleted after chrome store update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am a newbie in chrome extension development.

I am working on a chrome extension and I used chrome.storage.sync.set() to save the logged-in status and the auth token. When the chrome extension is updated to a newer version from the chrome store, this local data is deleted and I couldn't maintain the logged-in status. Each time the extension is updated, the user needs to log in again. Is there any other storage mechanism that is not affected by the version update?  Like preferences in Android?

Comment: Sync storage should persist. Sounds like a bug in the browser or in your code. This is as much as I can guess without seeing an MCVE or the extension proper.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check that